# Saving output of splice() to a text file

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following script

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

dat<-read.csv("sep_2015.csv",header=F)
dat$date<-seq(from=as.Date("2015-09-01"),to=as.Date("2015-12-31"),by="day")
dat %>%
   rownames_to_column() %>%
   filter(V2 < 90 &
       rollsum(V2 < 90, 7, fill = NA, align = "left") >=7 &
       rollsum(V1 > 2, 7, fill = NA, align = "left") >=7 &
       rollsum(V2 < 90, 20, fill = NA, align = "left") >= 15 ) %>%
                                              
slice(1)
```

The output is like this:

```
  rowname       V1       V2       date
  1      41 5.583102 45.83082 2015-10-11
```

I am processing multiple files (from sep_1979 to sep_2020) with the following names:

```
 ..... 
 sep_2014.csv
 sep_2015.csv
 sep_2016.csv
 ....
```

Sample data (sep_2015.csv):

```
structure(list(V1 = c(1.781016934, 5.245650757, 5.253808428, 
3.4500901, 1.904631502, 5.583155269, 5.29432007, 2.493240863, 
2.356109739, 2.505279709, 3.100681377, 4.352358556, 9.021734968, 
7.037204701, 1.946181317, 2.375415753, 4.818568252, 4.508796957, 
5.009930139, 3.413858254, 2.642863447, 4.496943406, 1.101138556, 
1.58130412, 5.907897257, 9.310602975, 12.8050039, 10.52127595, 
10.58324383, 5.719938811, 5.65915423, 10.23184856, 8.916484733, 
8.006767597, 7.623137477, 6.735120637, 3.913288259, 5.145787145, 
5.516434408, 3.766181753, 5.583101736, 8.62718523, 8.55994889, 
7.738160311, 9.428281922, 14.54588945, 21.1567956, 19.25095128, 
11.18693546, 6.459297562, 8.113929381, 6.791538854, 2.30569946, 
4.271416627, 7.043436661, 4.044279911, 4.841727481, 7.050044333, 
8.646260752, 4.475859911, 9.545056312, 6.185563838, 7.545238783, 
8.397502556, 6.124560982, 4.50970303, 6.682802556, 6.247809616, 
5.986996325, 4.525555447, 8.719674593, 8.245588214, 6.028287485, 
2.346912866, 2.842578055, 7.320520815, 6.337556706, 3.298882387, 
4.512427524, 8.360934487, 9.222761141, 8.958611924, 7.982833144, 
10.50259016, 8.866081434, 5.120412581, 11.46034903, 12.4205173, 
10.25257175, 2.466221616, 2.692953769, 0.681709806, 1.362974813, 
5.5663453, 9.601658711, 8.416295206, 3.412426219, 6.865540765, 
11.76102145, 12.0902957, 6.870356614, 2.020952899, 4.363628479, 
4.879838354, 4.059975788, 10.37719133, 10.37127041, 11.40995727, 
10.7018141, 11.43079722, 6.58367129, 6.628593068, 2.18586382, 
3.712579965, 2.874565445, 2.791741886, 4.21014224, 0.881548513, 
8.251492289, 7.62408847, 5.940576571, 8.981119084), V2 =     
c(121.0261069, 
85.00304523, 81.87989778, 103.7505395, 210.2369147, 264.2405565, 
282.9403406, 26.88123501, 19.2594093, 8.196100414, 45.26456729, 
58.17439097, 87.16714037, 109.3834486, 114.840361, 38.91351028, 
37.81463493, 24.49148024, 29.33726467, 13.51886983, 78.0736854, 
41.91203091, 55.80655486, 338.9064404, 338.2241727, 4.297849857, 
343.7324297, 266.8110122, 189.2300192, 118.7736246, 86.03606596, 
120.0474015, 151.7655159, 85.86331853, 67.23147222, 51.7641341, 
20.78357193, 271.0026858, 266.308435, 311.3070459, 45.83082398, 
64.93928317, 63.04855403, 35.94151677, 43.73557838, 55.52061899, 
55.9783368, 72.09428879, 81.11278896, 75.28379332, 56.17839757, 
46.85929244, 27.56930947, 64.41308939, 75.61366497, 66.62037577, 
43.60322015, 89.88800444, 101.8289993, 99.75479947, 80.43658344, 
78.52117729, 83.81080108, 91.30824192, 96.42780607, 101.3614562, 
118.3864844, 101.9711437, 103.8823967, 83.42613393, 74.27778556, 
97.92986085, 113.0191678, 147.4666885, 134.7889272, 104.79725, 
126.037476, 121.3500898, 83.21475735, 89.23421897, 92.92463803, 
85.92837336, 80.02208464, 55.23356116, 52.95700516, 30.38190174, 
64.76557575, 96.63946752, 86.73461083, 95.37929333, 62.17987768, 
12.7633562, 273.7881121, 76.47255644, 113.7227032, 149.0157726, 
78.67676081, 71.17172364, 89.33577561, 154.9133108, 221.6713695, 
85.69030561, 78.51796584, 97.6857188, 78.00024078, 67.04777272, 
66.22047934, 66.65994223, 68.62200021, 79.88214929, 84.2911525, 
98.45874358, 175.7545009, 214.3253056, 277.4996992, 348.4682651, 
97.83108644, 348.9214276, 49.4694104, 70.54130568, 79.26767621, 
80.66615013), date = structure(c(16679, 16680, 16681, 16682, 
16683, 16684, 16685, 16686, 16687, 16688, 16689, 16690, 16691, 
16692, 16693, 16694, 16695, 16696, 16697, 16698, 16699, 16700, 
16701, 16702, 16703, 16704, 16705, 16706, 16707, 16708, 16709, 
16710, 16711, 16712, 16713, 16714, 16715, 16716, 16717, 16718, 
16719, 16720, 16721, 16722, 16723, 16724, 16725, 16726, 16727, 
16728, 16729, 16730, 16731, 16732, 16733, 16734, 16735, 16736, 
16737, 16738, 16739, 16740, 16741, 16742, 16743, 16744, 16745, 
16746, 16747, 16748, 16749, 16750, 16751, 16752, 16753, 16754, 
16755, 16756, 16757, 16758, 16759, 16760, 16761, 16762, 16763, 
16764, 16765, 16766, 16767, 16768, 16769, 16770, 16771, 16772, 
16773, 16774, 16775, 16776, 16777, 16778, 16779, 16780, 16781, 
16782, 16783, 16784, 16785, 16786, 16787, 16788, 16789, 16790, 
16791, 16792, 16793, 16794, 16795, 16796, 16797, 16798, 16799, 
16800), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -122L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to:

(1) apply the above script for each file

(2) save the "date" from *splice (1)* into a text file

(3) the final output is a collection of dates from 1979 to 2020

How can I implement this in R? I'll appreciate any help on this.

Comment: `date` column is not present in the data by default you are creating it in the script? So every file has either 365 or 366 rows in them and you want to keep only those rows that satisfy the condition? Do you also want the filename in the final output?

Comment: The input files dont have dates. The data in each file are from September 1 to December 31 in each year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following solution :

- From each file name extract the year value.
- Create sequence of dates for that year using `paste` and add it as a column in the data.
- Filter the rows for the condition and select the 1st row from them.
- Combine the result into one file.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

all_files <- list.files(pattern = '^sep_.*\\.csv$')

map_df(all_files, function(file) {
        year <- parse_number(file)
        dates <- seq(as.Date(paste(year, 9, 1, sep = '-')), 
                     as.Date(paste(year, 12, 31, sep = '-')), by = 'day')

        dat <- read.csv(file,header=FALSE)
        dat %>%
          mutate(date = dates) %>%
          filter(V2 < 90 &
                   rollsum(V2 < 90, 7, fill = NA, align = "left") >=7 &
                   rollsum(V1 > 2, 7, fill = NA, align = "left") >=7 &
                   rollsum(V2 < 90, 20, fill = NA, align = "left") >= 15) %>%
          slice(1) %>%
          transmute(date, file = file)
}) -> result
```

`result` should look something like this -

```
result

#      date        filename
#1979-10-10    sep_1979.csv
#1980-11-21    sep_1980.csv
#1981-09-10    sep_1981.csv
#
#
```

You can then write `result` into csv or text file as per your choice.

```
#CSV
write.csv(result, 'result.csv', row.names = FALSE)
#TEXT
write.table(result, 'result.txt', row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: OMG..Thanks Ronak <3